# Drag/drop mail folder from Outlook to Explorer export to .pst file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

While working on large-scale projects, I collect all mail conversations pertaining to the project in a separate folder within Outlook. When the project is completed, I want to archive the entire folder, for reference purposes.

So my question is this:

Does anyone know of a tool/plugin for Outlook 2007/2010 that allows you to drag/drop a mailfolder from within Outlook, to a Windows Explorer window, exporting the folder as a .pst file, preserving folder structure and timestamps on mails?

I am doing this manually at the moment, but having a tool that would use simple drag/drop-functionality would greatly simplify my workflow for handling project-specific mail.

Answer (score 2):

Two options, though both do not meet your exact requirements

Option1
use the File Import/Export Function ...
Go to Menu->File->Import Export...
This opens the wizard, Select "Export to File"
Click Next, Select Personal Folder .pst
Select the folder that you want to export [your project folder]
Select the target file path and name, and complete the steps

Opiton2
Create a folder in Windows explorer, and then drag drop the individual messages by selecting them all. This will serve the same purpose and save all your email, except that it will be individual messages with extension .msg. You can import these back to outlook anytime you want

Comment: This is the way I handle it at the moment. Having a tool that lets me just drag/drop the folder into Windows Explorer would greatly simplify things for me, which was the point of my question. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a tool that will do this.

But you can create new PST files with Outlook to store the emails for eeach of your projects.  Here is a link showing how to drate a PST in Outlook 2010:  http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/4568/outlook-2010-how-to-create-a-new-outlook-data-file-pst/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Again, the whole point would be to simplify the process, by using simple drag/drop-functionality.

I have considered writing a plugin myself, but if there's already such a tool out there, I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Creating PST files or Archive function could be disabled by Policy rules…

Answer (score 0):

I am using outlook 2007 and cannot drag and drops messages from outlook to folders in windows explorer. 
My colleagues using the same can do so. 
Is there any settings requirement for this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the **Archive** function.  Go to "*Clean Up Tools*" and then select **Archive**.

Select the folder where all your project emails are, select a date and Outlook will move all emails older than the date selected into any selected PST file.